# CSS: What does "input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration" do?

Tags: css

I wonder what the the part `::-webkit-search-decoration` do in the CSS selector for `input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration`?

And why is this causing en DOM Exception error?

```
function is(selector, element) {
        var div = document.createElement("div"),
        matchesSelector = div.webkitMatchesSelector;
        return typeof selector == "string" ? matchesSelector.call(element, selector) : selector === element;
 }
 is('input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration', document.body);
```

Comment: I can confirm that the DOM exception is caused by the `"::-webkit-search-decoration"` part of the selector.

Comment: A DOM exception is also thrown when you try with `"::-webkit-progress-value"`. I guess that certain webkit-specific pseudo-elements simply cannot be used with `.webkitMatchesSelector()`.

Comment: Yes that's right they cannot be used

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It allows you to make search boxes look uniform across multiple browsers.  Chrome for instance has default styling for search boxes that does not fit into some designs.

here is a good link on the topic.
http://geek.michaelgrace.org/2011/06/webkit-search-input-styling/

Comment: Does the part after `::`have a name?

Comment: @Woho87 Selectors that start with `::` are called pseudo-elements. E.g. `::first-letter`. `::selection`, `::before`.

Comment: you are trying to match a search selector to a div?  Can you explain why you are doing that?

Comment: @Woho87 Selectors that start with one colon are pseudo-classes (e.g. `:hover`). Pseudo-elements start with two colons. Those are two different things. Pseudo-classes represent states. Pseudo-elements represent certain parts of the document that are not already represented by existing DOM elements (e.g. the first letter of a paragraph).

Comment: No pseudo classes and pseudo elements are having one colon: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-element-selectors

Comment: @Woho87 That section has been superseded by the "CSS3 Selectors" standard. Read about pseudo-elements here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements

Answer (score 0):

It just makes your search box little bit styled.As it is one of the property for css3 then it will not work on every browser.

Have a look in this link
http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/

Comment: What makes you think that it's a CSS3 selector? Have you checked?